# Strip Everything Except Alphanumeric unicode Characters with mb_ereg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, pcre, multibyte

I have PHP 5.2.9 on my apache web server, so `preg_replace` does not work on it.

I need to strip everything except alphanumeric unicode Characters.

Below line with `mb_ereg_replace` works but it does not strip special chars like #,@,and also ╘,╙,╥,...
i just need to a-zA-Z0-9 in english, and my unicode 'Farsi' language letters and digits. they are   ۹-۰ in digits and ی-ا in letters.

i don't know, if i need to introduce unicode characters in hex format or not, and if yes, how i can do.

`$str = mb_ereg_replace("[^\w ]", "", $str);`

Many Thanks

Comment: why would `preg_replace` not work on php 5.2.9? it's been part of PHP for much longer than that. have you tried it?

Comment: also -- bear in mind that php 5.2 was declared end of life nearly two years ago, and has been without any support ever since. If you're running it on a production server, you almost certainly have some big security holes.

Comment: `preg_replace` works fine  on my local php 5.3.6 
But the server run PHP 5.2.17 and i guess, it does not work on it.
I am sorry the server PHP is 5.2.17

Comment: both my above comments still apply: `preg_replace()` has been part of PHP since v4.0; it definitely works with 5.2. But even the latest version of 5.2 is still two years out of date. You need to upgrade the  server to 5.3 or 5.4. If you're using a web hosting company that won't upgrade, then you should be very worried about their suitability as a host.